# A .dtd show constant error, while the line seems okey when inserted into another file

Tags: dtd, tei

I compiled a .dtd for my recent project, but a line shows constant error:

`<!ELEMENT front ((%model.frontPart;|%model.pLike;|%model.pLike.front;|%model.global;)*,(((_DUMMY_model.div1Like,(_DUMMY_model.div1Like|%model.frontPart;|%model.global;)*)|(%model.divLike;,(%model.divLike;|%model.frontPart;|%model.global;)*)),((%model.divBottom;),(%model.divBottom;|%model.global;)*)?)?)>`

It says I missed an ')' from this line, while if I insert this code another .dtd, everything is alright. I don't know if you guys know how to help me, but I really appreciate if you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely one or more [parameter entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entity-decl) aren't declared in your DTD.

The reason I believe this is if I take the element declaration in your question and strip out all of the `%` and `;` to make those parameter entity references element names, and I create element declarations for them (just for testing), I don't get any validation errors (used Xerces for testing). This rules out an issue with parens.

For example, your DTD has `%model.frontPart;`. Your DTD would also need to have a declaration like:

```
<!ENTITY % model.frontPart "foo">
```

With `foo` being whatever the entity value is.

There needs to be an entity declaration for all of the parameter entity references in your example:

```
%model.divBottom;
%model.divLike;
%model.frontPart;
%model.global;
%model.pLike.front;
%model.pLike;
```

Compare the DTD you get the error in against the DTD you don't get the error in; does one have all of the entity declarations while one doesn't?

If this is not the case, please update your question with more information. (The entire DTD would be ideal.)

Comment: Yes, one of them went missing. Thank you very much.